# Referencing unchecked checkboxes with vbscript causes an error

Tags: html, checkbox, vbscript, asp-classic

I am running into a problem with my vbscript code.  My HTML code looks like this

```
<input type='checkbox' name='DisplayRow' id='DisplayRow1' />
<input type='checkbox' name='DisplayRow' id='DisplayRow2' />
<input type='checkbox' name='DisplayRow' id='DisplayRow3' />
```

This is done because above there is another checkbox that calls a javascript function that will check or uncheck all of the "DisplayRow" checkboxes.  The javascript function uses getElementsByName to return all of the checkboxes named "DisplayRow".

When the form's submit button is clicked the  action sends it to an ASP page (classic ASP) that grabs all of the objects on the calling form by using the Request.Form command.  The Request.Form command looks at the "name" attribute, not the "id" attribute of the object.

This seems to be working fine for all of the other form objects.  When it gets to the checkboxes because the "name" attribute uses the same name for all of the check boxes it returns an array.  The individual checkboxes can be accessed like this:

```
Request.Form("DisplayRow")(x)
```

Where x references the individual checkbox in the array.

If the checkboxes are checked I can loop through the array without any problems.  If 1 or more or all of the checkboxes are unchecked then when the code references the first checkbox in the array that is unchecked the page crashes.  Nothing is executed after the Request.Form command fails.

I have tried enclosing the Request.Form("DisplayRow")(x) in an IsNull function in an If statement but it still takes the program down.

Has anyone else ran into this and found a work around?

---

Edit

For some reason stackoverflow is not letting me add more than one comment.

@Cory. Thanks for the information

@jwatts1980. Count works but it does not let me know which of the checkboxes are checked.  If the count is greater than 0 I can loop through them but if the first one is unchecked I am right back where I started with a crashed page.

Comment: That is an expected behavior: unchecked checkbox values are not submitted to the server during a POST operation.

Comment: I think you can use `If Request("FieldName").Count > 0 Then` to check if any values exist.

Comment: Do not reply to comments by editing. Reply by adding your own comments please.

Comment: @ShadowWizard. Today the Stackoverflow site is letting me respond by comments.  Yesterday everytime I clicked the "add a comment" link I was take to the top of the page.  When I scrolled back down there was no edit box.  I was unable to add a comment here.  That is the reason why I put my comments at the end of my original question.

Comment: This means client side errors, first thing clear the browser's cache, second try a different browser. (if it happens again)

Comment: @ShadowWizard.  Thanks.  I didn't think about that.  If that ever happens again will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it this way because unchecked checkboxes will not be submitted in the post, only the checked ones.

I would approach this differently:

First I would add a `value` attribute to the checkboxes, as so:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='DisplayRow' id='DisplayRow1' value="1" />
<input type='checkbox' name='DisplayRow' id='DisplayRow2' value="2" />
<input type='checkbox' name='DisplayRow' id='DisplayRow3' value="3" />
```

Notice the value is the same as the index, this will be needed in the code.

Next I would use `.Split()` to gather the checkboxes selected in an array, since the values will come in as a string separated by comma, ie: `1,2,3` to your `.Form()` value.

```
Rows = Request.Form("DisplayRow")

'check if any are selected first
If Rows <> "" Then 

  'make an array with each value selected
  aRows = Split(Rows,",")

  'loop through your array and do what you want
  For i = lBound(aRows) to uBound(aRows)
    Response.Write "DisplayRow" & aRows(i) & " was Selected."
  Next

End If
```

This way you only process the results for the one's selected, and ignore the others.

Comment: It is a such simple solution that it is making me kick myself for not even thinking about that.  I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Splitting the value is not very elegant and will break if one of the submitted values has a comma inside it. Why not looping?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The value will always be numeric, so you can validate this by using `IsNumeric()`.  Additionally, how can this break when they're all checkboxes?  Unless someone forges the form and submits a post, then validating for an int value will resolve it.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="FooBar" value="a,b" />` will break your code, that will think two separate values have been submitted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's when you have to program around it by either using a different delimiter in your value, or encoding/decoding it before submit, also that's only if you're expecting comma's, whereas in OP's solution, its not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard And to answer your question **why not looping?** its because you can't loop through something that isn't there.  If the checkbox isn't selected, it won't show up in your post data.

Comment: But it won't show in your code either. Only the selected checkboxes' values would be sent.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I suppose you're right, guess it's just a matter of taste.  Regardless, the OP requires value fields.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found this essential for my library...

```
'GetPostData
'   Obtains the specified data item from the previous form get or post.
'Usage:
'   thisData = GetPostData("itemName", "Alternative Value")
'Parameters:
'   dataItem (string) - The data item name that is required.
'   nullValue (variant) - What should be returned if there is no value.
'Description:
'   This function will obtain the form data irrespective of type (i.e. whether it's a post or a get).
'Revision info:
'   v0.1.2 -    Inherent bug caused empty values not to be recognised.
'   v0.1.1 -    Converted the dataItem to a string just in case.
function GetPostData(dataItem, nullVal)
    dim rV
    'Check the form object to see if it contains any data...
    if request.Form = "" then
        if request.QueryString = "" then
            rV = nullVal
        else
            if request.QueryString(CStr(dataItem))="" then 
                rV = CStr(nullVal)
            else
                rV = request.QueryString(CStr(dataItem))
            end if
        end if
    else
        if request.Form(CStr(dataItem)) = "" then
            rV = CStr(nullVal)
        else
            rV = request.Form(CStr(dataItem))
        end if
    end if
    'Return the value...
    GetPostData = rV
end function
```

To use the function you simply pass in the form or query string item you're looking for and what to replace empty values with...

```
Dim x
x = GetPostData("chkFirstOne", false)
```

Comment: I like this.  I will incorprate this into my code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using your existing code by adding a single condition:

```
If Request.Form("DisplayRow").Count > 0 Then
    'your code here
Else  
    'consider adding message saying nothing was selected
End If
```

Comment: I have tried this.  There still is an inherent flaw.  It does not tell me which of the checkboxes has been checked.  If I have 3 checkboxes and the Count is 2 I still have to loop through all 3 to find the 2 and as soon as I hit the one that is not checked then the page stops.

Regardless, thanks for your help.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: That is true, if you want to know which of the three exactly was checked by getting its ID, you'll have to use some JS trickery.

Comment: Actually Tee Zee's solution above is working.  The value attribute helps identify the specific checkbox.  Prior to that I was trying to figure out how I would work JS into this because I know how to do this in JS but I couldn't figure out to work it in with out major changes.

Comment: Oh, totally missed that you were not using value. Cheers then! :)